# Not possible: this pointer as a default argument. Why?

Tags: c++, arguments, this, default-value, this-pointer

The following code won't compile. Why?

```
class A
{
   int j;
   void f( int i = this->j );
}
```

Edit, for clarity. This is what I was trying to do, using less lines of code...

```
class A
{
   void f( int i ){};
   void f( );
   int j;
};

void A::f()
{
    f( j );
}
```

Comment: Because the instance is not in scope inside the argument declaration...?

Comment: "...The expression can combine functions that are visible in the current scope, constant expressions, and global variables. The expression cannot contain local variables or non-static class-member variables..."

Comment: @Jordan Kaye - I have edited, to answer your question... I was trying to use less lines of code... as described above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Default argument values are bound at compile time.

"this" is only defined at run time, so can't be used.

See here for a fuller explanation:
[Must default function parameters be constant in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334882/must-default-function-parameters-be-constant-in-c)

Comment: but why was C++ designed like this, that default arguments have to be bound at compiled time?...

Comment: @alexandreC that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already commented on the reason this doesn't work. From one of the comments:

> "...The expression can combine functions that are visible in the
>   current scope, constant expressions, and global variables. The
>   expression cannot contain local variables or non-static class-member
>   variables..."

You could use `optional` to eliminate the extra function although I'm not sure it's clearer:

`void f( boost::optional<int> i = boost::none ) { if(!i) i = j; ... }`