# Default parameter issue (c++)

Tags: c++, class, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nonstatic member as a default argument of a nonstatic member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539406/nonstatic-member-as-a-default-argument-of-a-nonstatic-member-function)
>   [Why can member variables not be used as defaults for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678627/why-can-member-variables-not-be-used-as-defaults-for-parameters)

Ok I apologize in advance if I am not seeing something very simplistic here or forgetting some fundamental rule of C++ but I am not sure why this does not work as expected.

Here is a example of code that I can't get to work

```
class Foo
{
private:
    Bar *ptrBar;
public:
    void doSomething(int x, Bar *p = ptrBar);
}
```

The compiler is having an issue with the default parameter to this function. Is there some reason why this wouldn't work.

Basically doSomething would do some operation on a Bar object, and I want it to be the one pointed to by ptrBar by default. Everything seems sound unless I am forgetting something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time the compiler is evaluating this, `ptrBar` is not set.  Therefore your default parameter has no  default value.

Why not use a default of null and if `p` in `doSomething()` is null then use the `ptrBar` member.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great idea. Simple and to the point.

Answer (score 5):

You're not allowed to use class members as default parameters, nor `this`.

#### 8.3.6 Default arguments [dcl.fct.default]

> [...] Similarly, a non-static member shall not be used in a default argument, even if it is not
>   evaluated, unless it appears as the id-expression of a class member access expression (5.2.5) or unless it is
>   used to form a pointer to member (5.3.1). [...]

The best workaround would be to use overloading:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    Bar *prtBar;
public:
    void doSomething(int x, Bar *p);
    void doSomething(int x)
    {
        soSomething(x, ptrBar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that is how I dealt with it. But what that did is created a whole bunch of overloaded functions. I was just hoping to de-clutter my code.