# In C++, does the scope of a named parameter include the expression for its default value?

Tags: c++, scope, c++14, overloading, default-value

Example: Is this legal C++14?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

static int d() {
    return 42;
}

static int e(int d = d()) {
    return d;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << e() << " " << e(-1) << std::endl;
}
```

g++ 5.4 with `-std=c++14` likes it, but clang++ 3.8 with `-std=c++14` complains:

```
samename.cxx:3:23: error: called object type 'int' is not a function or function pointer
static int e(int d = d()) {return d;}
                     ~^
```

Comment: also reproducible with clang 3.9.1 http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8RCXqcgCZzbN7l5o

Comment: Maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334882/must-default-function-parameters-be-constant-in-c

Comment: My common sense tells me clang is right in this situation, as the `d` parameter shadows the `d` global function. Don't quote me on this though.

Comment: I think @DeiDei is right: `static int e(int d = ::d()) {return d;}` compiles. see [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1Ip3mTE8YKRdte6A)

Comment: Looks like GCC is wrong here. Could you file a bug report?

Comment: I used to find these questions interesting, but now my first reaction is.. who cares? Such code wouldn't pass review anyway. Pick a better name for your variables and functions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [basic.scope.pdecl/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#scope.pdecl-1):

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete
>   declarator and before its initializer (if any), except as noted below.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> unsigned char x = 12;
> { unsigned char x = x; }
> ```
>
> Here the second `x` is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value.

Clang is consistent with this section of the standard. GCC only seems to apply it in `{block}`.

Given:

```
constexpr int d() {return 42;}
```

The following fails in Clang, but works in GCC:

```
static int e(int d = d()) {return d;}
             // This ^^d should refer to the new name that shadows ::d()
```

The following fails both in Clang and GCC:

```
void func(){
    int d = d();
         // ^^d here refers to the new name that shadowed ::d();
 }
```

Comment: Are we sure that this applies to default arguments? There are a few ways in which those differ from bog-standard initialisations. Basically: is this really an initializer?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, *"is this really an initializer?"* - As per [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default#1), I'll say yes, it is.

Answer (score 11):

It seems it is not legal: see the C++14 specification ([section 3.3.2 - Point of declaration](http://cpp14.centaur.ath.cx/basic.scope.pdecl.html)).

```
int x = 5;
{ int x = x; } // second x is initialized with its own undetermined state
{ int x[x]; }  // declares an array with 5 elements, since the declaration of 
               // second x is not complete when the first x is used
```

In your case, the declaration of `d` is complete, so when you use `d()` you're referring to the variable, not the function.